# Twisted protocol to handle concatenated TCP stream with custom frame structure?

Tags: python, tcp, twisted

I got a job to build a long-pull TCP socket server as device server. Twisted is selected during my development. It works fine with my Python device simulator. However the real device send out concatenated (or combined) TCP packets. I know that is normal in real network and device, although the TCP packet is quite short.

It has three frame structure:

> \xFDAA + "realtime_data" + \xCCDD (length is fixed at 150B)
>
> \xFDCC + "extra_data" + \xCCDD (length is fixed at 190B)
>
> \xFDCC + "extra_data" + \xCCDD (length is fixed at 192B)

Obviously, \xFDAA \xFDCC are headers, and \xCCDD is EOT. So they do have bondaries. And they also implied fixed length, without defined in protocol itself.

However, I have no idea how to handle that concatenated packets of custom frame with exiting Twisted methods. During my developer, I used dataReceiver.

So far I am trying to parse the packet and store it in a buffer in Factory of protocol. When each new packet arrived, I will combined the previous buffered data with new one to parse (combined if concatenated, seperate them if combined packets received ... But that seems dirty).

I have checked FAQ of twistedmatrix.com. It recommended following solutions:

```
LineReceiver (with \r\n ending chars) 
NetstringReceiver (with callback for every string received) 
Int8/16/32Receiver (with prefix length information)
```

And then also AMP and PB high level messaging is recommended.

I will like to hear any sugguestings from twisted experts on how to implement it with twisted officially. And URL/demo code is highly helpful.

Comment: What is "long pull"?  Do you mean "long polling"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for my poor English. It should be "long polling", which means the device will start the connection to server, keep it and only disconnect when device decide to drop the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the set of `LineReceiver`, `NetstringReceiver`, `Int8/16/32Receiver`,
`AMP`, or `PB` are applicable to your problem, as they are all implementations
of specific framing (and in the case of the latter two, messaging) protocols.
You, instead, have a custom protocol you want to implement.

Luckily this is relatively straightforward: Twisted delivers you data via your
`IProtocol` implementations' `dataReceived` method.

The best way to deal with this sort of thing is actually to implement a simple
function first rather than worrying about exactly how it is going to be plugged
into Twisted.  In your case, you need a function that parses your protocol;
but, since `dataReceived` might deliver you a partial packet, you need to
ensure that the function returns 2 things: the parsed data, and any remaining
buffer.  Once you have such a function, you can then plug it in to a `Protocol`
subclass quite easily.

Your explanation of the protocol wasn't very clear, so this might not be quite
correct, but I interpreted your description of the message format to be like this:

```
octet 0xFD
octet 0xAA
150 octets of "realtimeData"
octet 0xCC
octet 0xDD
octet 0xFD
octet 0xCC
190 octets of "extraData1"
octet 0xCC
octet 0xDD
octet 0xFD
octet 0xCC
192 octets of "extraData2"
octet 0xCC
octet 0xDD
```

in other words, a single protocol message is 544 bytes long, and contains 3
fields and 12 bytes of padding which must be correct.

So let's first write a `Message` class that represents a message with these
three fields, using the standard library `struct` module to parse and serialize
its fields:

```
from struct import Struct

class Message(object):
    format = Struct(
        "!" # Network endian; always good form.
        "2s" # FD AA
        "150s" # realtimeData
        "4s" # CC DD FD CC
        "190s" # extra1
        "4s" # CC DD FD CC
        "192s" # extra2
        "2s" # CC DD
    )

    def __init__(self, realtimeData, extra1, extra2):
        self.realtimeData = realtimeData
        self.extra1 = extra1
        self.extra2 = extra2

    def toBytes(self):
        return self.format.pack(
            b"\xFD\xAA", self.realtimeData, b"\xCC\xDD\xFD\xCC", self.extra1,
            b"\xCC\xDD\xFD\xCC", self.extra2, b"\xCC\xDD"
        )

    @classmethod
    def fromBytes(cls, octets):
        [fdaa, realtimeData, ccddfdcc, extra1, ccddfdcc2, extra2,
         ccdd] = cls.format.unpack(octets)
        # verify message integrity
        assert fdaa == b"\xFD\xAA"
        assert ccddfdcc == b"\xCC\xDD\xFD\xCC"
        assert ccddfdcc2 == b"\xCC\xDD\xFD\xCC"
        assert ccdd == b"\xCC\xDD"
        return cls(realtimeData, extra1, extra2)

    @classmethod
    def parseStream(cls, streamBytes):
        sz = cls.format.size
        messages = []
        while len(streamBytes) >= sz:
            messageData, streamBytes = streamBytes[:sz], streamBytes[sz:]
            messages.append(cls.fromBytes(messageData))
        return messages, streamBytes
```

The important part here for interfacing with Twisted is the final
`parseStream` method, which turns a pile of bytes into a pile of messages, and
the remaining bytes that weren't parsed yet.  We can then have a `Protocol`
make sense of an actual network stream, like so:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    buffer = b""
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        messages, self.buffer = Message.parseStream(self.buffer + data)
        for message in messages:
            self.messageReceived(message)
    def messageReceived(self, message):
        "do something useful with a message"
```

Rather than calling `self.messageReceived`, you might want to call a method on
some other attribute of `self`, or perhaps relay the `Message` object up to the
factory associated with this protocol.  It's up to you!  Since you said that
you want to "parse the packet and store it in a buffer in Factory", perhaps you
just want to do `self.factory.messagesBuffer.append(message)`.  Hopefully this
seems cleaner than your "packet concatenation" approach, which was not
described clearly enough for me to understand what you thought was distasteful
about it.

Comment: Thanks. @Glyph, Actually the binary protocols mentioned in my questions are 3 kinds of messages. And I convinced customer to upgrade the protocol with datalen field. Now it is "header + datalen + payload + terminator". Up to now, I still implement the buffer and parser/decoder with datareceived(). You method is better, and I will use in my latest release.

Comment: Thanks for following up - glad the solution helped!